# google chrome. linux. XDG-OPEN keep asking me (forever) what to do with magnet links

Tags: linux, google-chrome, xdg, magnet-links, qbittorrent

(i'm on latest chrome beta (64) but it is happening in all the previous version of chrome i used.)

when i press magnet links in google chrome, i get this card:
[Open xdg-open?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJnNc.png)

so i mark to always open these types of links... and then press open xdg-open.
now qBittorrent is starting to work. everything is OK.

but, if i press another magnet link, it again pop up this card and ask me what to do. it always do that and never save what i choose for later.

i have `qbittorrent.desktop` in `/usr/share/applications`

the beginning of `qbittorrent.desktop` is:

```
[Desktop Entry]                                           
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;P2P;Qt;                   
Exec=qbittorrent %U                                       
GenericName=BitTorrent client                             
Comment=Download and share files over BitTorrent          
Icon=qbittorrent                                          
MimeType=application/x-bittorrent;x-scheme-handler/magnet;
Name=qBittorrent                                          
Terminal=false                                            
Type=Application                                          
StartupNotify=false                                       
StartupWMClass=qbittorrent                                
Keywords=bittorrent;torrent;magnet;download;p2p;
```

also in `~/.config/mimeapps.list` i have this:

```
[Default Applications]                             
text/html=google-chrome-beta.desktop               
x-scheme-handler/http=google-chrome-beta.desktop   
x-scheme-handler/https=google-chrome-beta.desktop  
x-scheme-handler/about=google-chrome-beta.desktop  
x-scheme-handler/unknown=google-chrome-beta.desktop
x-scheme-handler/magnet=qbittorrent.desktop
```

if i command `xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/magnet` i get `qbittorrent.desktop` result.

also if i command: `xdg-mime default qbittorrent.desktop x-scheme-handler/magnet` nothing is changed and problem exist.

last thing, if i open terminal and command:

`xdg-open magnet:?xt=magnet-link-continue-here` it opens qbittorrent with the link without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

it was a bug in chrome:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=788431
fixed now on latest chrome beta (maybe on stable also).

Comment: Broken again? This bug and its numerous duplicates suggests so: https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1776873  Certainly under Ubuntu 19.10 I can't open anything from the browser anymore.

Comment: keeps prompting on debian testing tool frustrating.

Comment: This worked for me. https://community.shotgunsoftware.com/t/how-to-fix-chrome-protocol-handler-always-open-these-types-of-links-pop-up-when-opening-rv-through-rvlink/4306

Comment: @AlfredoDiaz This didn't work for me. Chrome 81.0.4044.92 on Ubuntu 19.10. Still cannit select auto open / always open, etc and need to manually click it each time.

Answer (score 2):

This solution works for me on Google Chrome 84.0.4147.89, for specific types of xdg links. For example, if the link in question is `magnet://someurl`, you can use:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/ && echo '{ "URLWhitelist": ["magnet://*"] }' |sudo tee /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/whitelist.json
```